# Make a Form with ffmpeg action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I would like to know if it would be possible to create a form with ffmpeg actions on a Rails application. Because there is not a lot of documentation on this.
On my application, users can upload a video, but I would like those who can, through a form with for example radio button, to manipulate their video. For example by adding a Reverb effect on the audio. Or add audio over the video. But I can't find documentation on a form with ffmpeg.

But how to link ffmpeg action in a form on rails ? If you have an example it will help me a lot.

Thank you !

Comment: What you are asking is not specific to ffmpeg. The generic version of your question is: is it possible to run an executable from a Rails application? The answer is yes, everything you describe is possible to do. 1) User uploads video, 2) User selects ffmpeg settings from a form, 3) You run ffmpeg with the desired settings on the video file uploaded in step 1. These are all possible to do, but each one is a separate task which you need to implement. Start by learning how to upload a file with Rails, for example.

Comment: My application is already capable of uploading video to my server. But now I would like to know if it is possible to create a form with the streamio-ffmpeg gem. Or do you have a link or documentation to create this type of form that sends actions to ffmpeg?